# How to add Scrolling Background Effect in iOS SpriteKit.

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, sprite-kit

I want to add scrolling background effect to my scene. For example when user gesture is to right side or left side, then background should scroll horizontally and if upside or to downside then background should scroll vertically to add effect as a character is really moving.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Adventure game code explained by Apple for SpriteKit. The section that has to do with your question is "Moving the Camera". Essentially it is adding the nodes to a "World" node and then moving the "World" node around based on user input or character movement.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/AdventureArchitecture/AdventureArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013140